# How to run watch app in the background using WKExtendedRuntimeSession

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit

Thank you for taking a look at this page.
I am developing a Watch App and would like to do some background data processing in SwiftUI.
I tried to run it using WKExtendedRuntimeSession, but it doesn't seem to be running when it becomes inactive.

```
import SwiftUI


@main
struct FirebaseExample_Watch_AppApp: App {
    var session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()

init() {
    session.start()
    
    // MARK:- Extended Runtime Session Delegate Methods
    func extendedRuntimeSessionDidStart(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {
        print(1)
    }

    func extendedRuntimeSessionWillExpire(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {
        print(2)
    }
        
    func extendedRuntimeSession(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession, didInvalidateWith reason: WKExtendedRuntimeSessionInvalidationReason, error: Error?) {
        print(3)
    }
}


var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        
        ContentView()
    }
}
}
```

But the result is nothing happens the moment I put my arm down and the app screen disappears.
I alse tried to do this;

```
init() {
    　　　　　　　　func startTimerButtonPressed() {
        print(WKApplicationState.RawValue())
        var session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
        session.start()
        print(WKExtendedRuntimeSessionState.RawValue())
        }
```

The results are all zeros and do not appear to be initiated.

If you are familiar with WKExtendedRuntimeSession, please let me know how to run it.

Reference
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextendedruntimesession

Comment: Where do you set your delegate? And why are these functions in what seems to be the `init` of the `App` struct?

Comment: I apologize as I am still a beginner, but when I run it with other structs (e.g. @main
struct Example_Watch_AppApp: App ), I get the error "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';’."

What do you think I should do?

Comment: session.delegate = self
will result in the following error "Cannot assign value of type 'ContentView' to type '(any WKExtendedRuntimeSessionDelegate)?"

Comment: I really think you should try to start with the basics. What delegates are and how they are used in swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting a delegate for your session. A possible implementation would look like this:

```
@main
struct TestWatchOSOnly_Watch_AppApp: App {
    
    @State var session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
    //define and create the delegate
    @State var delegate = WKDelegate()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear{
                    //create a new session
                    session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
                    //assign the delegate
                    session.delegate = delegate
                    //start the session
                    session.start()
                }
        }
    }
}
// define the delegate and its methods
class WKDelegate: NSObject, WKExtendedRuntimeSessionDelegate{
    
    func extendedRuntimeSession(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession, didInvalidateWith reason: WKExtendedRuntimeSessionInvalidationReason, error: Error?) {
        print(reason.rawValue)
    }
    
    func extendedRuntimeSessionDidStart(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {
        print("did start")
    }
    
    func extendedRuntimeSessionWillExpire(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {
        print("will expire")
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: This has now been executed. I deeply appreciate your thoughtful response. I am just beginning my studies and will make an effort to study swiftui!